# If an arrow category is like a path what's like a cylinder?

Tags: category-theory

The arrow category is isomorphic to a functor category out of the interval category.

$$\mathrm{Arr}( C) = [\mathrm I, C]$$

It is like a very simple/degenerate case of a path object.

A "loop" speaking loosely would just be an arrow (possibly identity?) with equal source and target.

You would expect it to have an adjoint something like

$$? = C \times \mathrm{I}$$

And a sort of "suspension" category would be some sort of quoitent or pushout that I don't quite understand equating (x, 0) and (y, 1).

But I can't really figure out how to conceptualize these as concrete things. What does it mean to be an object of a "cylinder" category?

Maybe you could think of it as mapping between source/targets?

Comment: This is very unclear. Certainly $C\times I$ is like a cylinder, but what are you looking for in the $?$

Comment: @Kevin Arlin I was trying to play around with and better understand some homotopy/topology stuff. I felt it could help with some weird foundational quirks. In particular the single sorted definition https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category reminds me a lot of path stuff. I figured looking at the other side of things would help. An object/identity arrow is a loop {x| (s x, t x) =(x, x)}. I understood loops in category terms but I can't understand cylinders and suspensions. I will edit and clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a lengthy comment than an answer, but I hope it is relevant enough to not be annoying...

As you noted the free living arrow $[1]=0\rightarrow 1$ gives rise to the arrow category of a category $\mathscr{C}$ via the functor category $\operatorname{Fun}([1],\mathscr{C})$. Similarly any totally ordered set $[n]=0\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow ... \rightarrow n$ gives rise to some sort of a category of paths/walks of length $n$ in $\mathscr{C}$ via $\operatorname{Fun}([n],\mathscr{C})$.

The category of categories $\mathsf{Cat}$ is cartesian closed, so we have an adjunction
$$-\times [n] \dashv \operatorname{Fun}([n], -).$$
The product $\mathscr{C}\times [n]$ can be computed to consist of $n+1$ copies of $\mathscr{C}$ with a fixed order and consecutive copies joined together. So in some sense it does constitute a cylinder.

The problem with this constructions is the following though: it is good practice to have different path-spaces respectively different cylinders to be at least weakly equivalent. But in this case there is (to my knowledge) no good notion of weak equivalence of categories making $\operatorname{Fun}([1],\mathscr{C}) \sim \operatorname{Fun}([n],\mathscr{C})$ true. The issue is with the directedness and different length of the categories $[n]$.

We *can* remedy the situation by considering the free living iso $I=0\overset{\rightarrow}{\underset{\leftarrow}{}}1$ and any chain $I_n$ of $n$ copies of it. Then everything mentioned works out analogously with the difference that eg. $\mathscr{C}\times I$ and $\mathscr{C}\times I_n$ are equivalent as categories.

This is not just a nice little fact. A *homotopy equivalence* with respect to the interval $I$ in $\mathsf{Cat}$ is precisely an equivalence of categories. In fact it gives a whole homotopy theory of categories (you may want to look up the folk/categorical model structure). As I understand it, developing category theory out of this perspective constitutes Prof. Cisinskis approach to $\infty$-categories.

I haven’t seen the construction of say unreduced suspension be written out or used anywhere yet. But it might be worth to have a look in the case of the interval being the free living iso.

Answer (score 2):

The way I like to think about $\mathcal C \times I$ is that it classifies natural transformations.

Just like $X \times I$ classifies homotopies for topological spaces $X$.

Natural transformations $\phi:\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal G$ between two functors $\mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal D$ are in bijection with functors $H$ that fit into the diagram.

[image]

We simply set $H((c,0) \rightarrow (c,1)) = \phi_c$ to establish this bijection.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the question is, but the "cylinder category" $C \times I$ is just the usual [product of categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_category) of $C$ and $I$, and indeed we have $\mathrm{Hom}(C \times I,D) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(C,\mathrm{Hom}(I,D))$. So this product category is already what you are looking for. The [geometric realization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization+of+categories) $|-| : \mathbf{Cat} \to \mathbf{Top}$ (when done with a convenient category of topological spaces) commutes with finite products, so indeed $|C \times I| = |C| \times [0,1]$ is a cylinder in the topological sense.

You also asked for a "suspension category" $S(C)$ which should be a quotient of $C \times I$ in which $(x,0) \cong (x',0)$ and $(x,1) \cong (x',1)$ for all $x,x' \in C$, and such that the geometric realization is $|S(C)| = S(|C|)$. In fact, we might just adjoin these isomorphisms to $C \times I$, and keep the same objects. Any morphism $x \to x'$ in $C$ already induces a morphism $(x,0) \to (x',0)$, and we identify it with the adjoined isomorphism (similarly for $1$).

Comment: So manually working out adjoining isomorphisms myself you would have $\mathrm{Hom} (A, 0) (B, 0) = A \leftrightarrow B$, and $\mathrm {Hom} (A, 1) (B, 1) = A \leftrightarrow B$ and $Hom (A, 0) (B, 1) = A \rightarrow B$ and $\mathrm{Hom} (A, 1) (B, 0) = \emptyset$ right? The construction still just doesn't feel right to me. There's no intuitive meaning to it even though arrows and loops have lots of meaning. I've tried to diagram it out but im still not good at commutativity diagrams

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cograph+of+a+profunctor#in_category_theory ahah feels cography idk for sure though